# ¿Cómo hacer que un Listbox se actualice cuando agrego datos?

Tags: excel, vba, microsoft-office, macros

Sucede que estoy creando un Userform que tiene un `ListBox` que contiene la información de una hoja (N° de Factura, Cliente, Monto, etc.) y me gustaría poder filtrar a través de un `ComboBox` por `Cliente` (por ejemplo) y que la `Listbox` me muestre la tabla filtrada.

[Enlace a archivo](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4B7v0UZxizCSld4bFR4d2JzVkU)

A continuación el código del `UserForm` que estoy trabajando.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If ComboBox1.Value <> "" Then ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tabla2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=ComboBox1.Value
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tabla2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2
End Sub
```

RowSource de TextBox ="Tabla2"

Comment: Es necesario que subas tu archivo, para asi poder ayudarte mas facil.

Comment: Estimado, como podría subir el Archivo?

Comment: Debes apretar sobre : [Editar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/60128/edit) Alli se inicia la edicion de tu pregunta y puedes agregar el codigo

Comment: Subí el archivo a Google Drive, espero que sirva. El Userform al que me refiero en la pregunta es "Userform 2". Logré poner el botón para filtrar, pero no se refleja el filtro en el ListBox

Comment: @IvanBotero cuidado con los términos, subir un archivo no es lo mismo que editar la pregunta y poner el código. Subir un archivo es completamente algo muy diferente.

Comment: @Flxtr Si, aunque crei que el OP se referia a subir el contenido del archivo, no a subir el archivo literalmente

Comment: Estimados, si existe algún problema con el hecho de subir el archivo puedo quitar el enlace.

Comment: @IvanBotero
Espero puedan ayudarme.
Saludos